# Run the module in python 2.7.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I created a class Rectangle and try to save to a module.

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Dropbox/using Python 3/test.py", line 2, in <module>
from Rectangle import Rectangle
  ImportError: No module named Rectangle
```

My code:

```
import math
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width = 1 , height = 2):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def getPerimeter (self):
        return (self.width + self.height) * 2

    def getArea (self):
        return self.width * self.height

    def setSides( self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

Another file run to test Rectangle module:

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle

def main ():
    Rectangle1 = Rectangle(4, 40)
    print  "The area  of the rectangle,", Rectangle1.width, "is width and", Rectangle1.height, "is height, are", Rectangle1.getArea()
    print  "The perimeter of the rectangle,", Rectangle1.width, "is width and", Rectangle1.height, "is height, are", Rectangle1.getPerimeter()

    Rectangle2 = Rectangle(3.5, 35.7)
    print  "The area of the rectangle,", Rectangle2.width, "is width and", Rectangle2.height, "is height, are", Rectangle2.getArea()
    print  "The perimeter of the rectangle,", Rectangle2.width, "is width and", Rectangle2.height, "is height, are", Rectangle2.getPerimeter()

main ()
```

Comment: Okay.. So what is the problem?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dropbox/using Python 3/*.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Rectangle import Rectangle
ImportError: No module named Rectangle

Comment: Is the Python file containing the definition of your `Rectangle` class named `Rectangle.py`? Is that file in your Python path, i.e., in one of the directories in the `sys.path` list?

Comment: Or you can try to put the Rectangle.py and the test.py in the same path and try to run test.py if you get a  Rectangle.pyc, your test.py should run normally.

Comment: What is the python file name of your Rectangle class?

Comment: The easiest thing that should work is put the both the `Rectangle.py` and `test.py` files in the same folder. Also, since you're using `from Rectangle import Rectangle`, make sure you didn't name the first file `rectangle.py`.

Comment: I named Exercise07 01.py of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code, but with how your files are named and arranged in directories. Because your question currently contains no information about what your files are named and in which directories they are, we cannot help you much further. At a minimum, the `Rectangle` class should be in a file named `Rectangle.py` and it needs to be in the current directory, or in a directory on your `PYTHONPATH`. It is also possible to have a directory called `Rectangle` which then needs to contain a file `__init__.py` which may be empty, or contain module-wide Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed codes:

**from Exercise0701 import Rectangle**

Since I saved the name of file is Exercise0701.py, it can not find the file name of Rectangle in the computer.

I makes the mistakes.

Thank you for everyone.

Comment: Please mark this (or another answer, if you like) as accepted, so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this inside test.py,

import sys

sys.path.append("Rectangle class module path")

import "Rectangle class module"

Comment: Module's can't have spaces in their names.